# What is the difference between sudo command and sudo bash -c command?

Tags: sudo

Is there any difference between the following two commands?

```
sudo su - root
```

and

```
sudo bash -c 'su - root'
```

It looks like a silly question but I believe there is some benefit on security by only allowing the second one. I just do not know what is the benefit for that. So could you give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo su` lauches `su` directly with super user privileges, while `sudo bash` lauches the shell first and then executes the command with `bash -c`.

The main difference would be that your `.bashrc` script will be run before executing the `su - root` command. The outcome depends on that.

Use cases:

- Lauch `bash` with elevated privilges, using your own password:

  ```
  sudo bash
  ```
- Lauch shell as user `root`, with root's password:

  ```
  su - root
  ```
- Lauch shell as user `root`, with your own password:

  ```
  sudo su - root
  ```
- Everything already covered, no really need for:

  ```
  sudo bash -c 'su - root'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Sudo won’t allow you to natively do command redirection; for example, the following won’t work — permission is still denied on write attempt:

```
sudo echo -e “\x23\x21/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash\napt-get update\napt-get -y dist-upgrade” > /usr/bin/distupgrade && sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/distupgrade
```

Wrapping everything in `sudo bash -c` solves this problem:

```
sudo bash -c “echo -e \”\x23\x21/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash\napt-get update\napt-get -y dist-upgrade\” > /usr/bin/distupgrade && chmod a+x /usr/bin/distupgrade”
```

Answer (score 1):

You should, instead, use

```
sudo -i
```

su and sudo are two very different ways to escalate privileges, but in the end both allow you to run commands as your target user - in your case root.

sudo uses your username and your groups to decide wether or not you can execute a command, while su expects you to know the password of your target user - except for root, who can become anyone without password.

When you run `sudo su - root` you are authenticating twice, in practice to create a shell as root, which you can do by running `sudo -i`

Comment: I need to get an elevated shell. My user is in `sudoers` so I can use `sudo`. The only way to keep defined aliases (and as a bonus also the prompt and other things defined in my user's `.bashrc`) I have found is to use `sudo -E bash`. When I use `sudo -E su`, those things are not preserved. Is it wrong to use `sudo -E bash` for any reason, please?